# Send billing address using Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I need to be able to pass the shipping address and billing address to PayPal using the Express Checkout product within the SetExpressCheckout call. My site checks to see whether the users’ shipping address is within the customers delivery area and proceeds to PayPal.

If I send PayPal the shipping address only or try to pass them the billing address it only populates the billing address with the shipping address which is very confusing for the user.

Can I pass PayPal separate billing and shipping addresses?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one to find that weird that Paypal put the shipping address as the billing address...

Answer (score 2):

Express Checkout does not deal with Billing Addresses as that is collected by PayPal on the hosted page and not returned to the merchant for security and privacy.

Express Checkout is designed to send the customer over to PayPal before the cart obtains the address information. PayPal then sends back the shipping address the customer chose. PayPal collects the billing address information and validates it, if applicable, but does not return that.

Comment: I need to pass the shipping address and I stop the user changing this by passing ADDROVERRIDE parameter.

Can I stop the billing address being populated with this data as its very confusing for the user?

Comment: Looked over the API reference and no, it will default the billing address for guest checkout to be the shipping address passed and customers can override this.